# Page Timeout When Minimee is Enabled

Tags: minimee

I have a template that is making a request to remote CSS & JS files that are hosted on the same server, different domain:

```
{exp:minimee:js}
    <script>https://www.remotesite.tld/assets/js/plugins/cycle.js</script>
    <script>https://www.remotesite.tld/assets/js/init/index.js</script>
{/exp:minimee:js}
```

When I try to load the page, the browser gets stuck in loading-mode for several minutes before throwing a "page not available" error.

If I disable Minimee in my config, the page loads without issue:

```
$env_config['minimee']['disable'] = 'y';
```

No server errors are logged when this happens.

- EE 2.9.0
- Minimee 2.1.12

Comment: Does anybody know why this is resulting in a "page not available" browser-side error instead of a HTTP timeout error or just Minimee failing silently?

Comment: What happens if you copy those assets to local and source them local? Wondering if its a remote thing.

Comment: Can you try changing Minimee's settings to use file_get_contents() instead of cURL when fetching remotes?

Comment: @JohnDWells FGC worked! If you want to post that as an actual answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Minimee tries to fetch "remote" assets using cURL; if you find that your server setup somehow doesn't like this, you can try configuring Minimee to use file_get_contents() as an alternative.

--

If it is possible for Minimee (or PHP more specifically) to access those assets via the filesystem, then you can try to "map" the external URL to the physical location, with a combination of setting your base_path and base_urls. You can pass these as tags rather than global configs:

```
{exp:minimee:js
    base_path="/path/to/www.remotesite.tld"
    base_url="http://www.remotesite.tld"}
    ...
{/exp:minimee:js}
```

With that set, when Minimee encounters that remotesite URL, it will replace it with the base path, and then attempt to fetch their contents.

Answer (score 0):

What is the HTTP Status code? 500?

It could be related to a bug on 2.9.0
See here for a fix: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20471/site-index-template-is-rendered-after-the-404-template